# Imploding PHP Array Into HTML Textarea

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo an imploded PHP array into a textbox. The array is made by reading a file via the file() function, like this:

```
$bad_phrases=file('bad_phrases.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

The array is then used in the script and I need to output it again in HTML:

```
<textarea>
    <?php
    echo implode("\n", $bad_phrases);
    ?>
</textarea>
```

However, I get some weird formatting in the textarea when I try to do this. It comes out as:

```
"       adsfsf
asdfsd
sddsds  "
```

However, When bad_phrases.txt is viewed on a browser, it shows up fine:

```
adsfsf
asdfsd
sddsds
```

And `var_dump` shows that the array is fine:

```
var_dump($bad_phrases);
array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "adsfsf" [1]=> string(6) "asdfsd" [2]=> string(6) "sddsds" }
```

So what am I doing wrong with the Implode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the space inside:

```
<textarea><?php echo implode("\n", $bad_phrases);?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have some additional whitspace in your output, here's where it comes from:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<textarea>` code does not ignore whitespace, the new lines and tabs that you have are messing it up. Basically, just move the tags to something like this:

```
<textarea><?php
    echo implode("\n", $bad_phrases);
?></textarea>
```